# php mail() often not reaching the address

Tags: php, wordpress, gmail

this is my problem, essentially - I set up a wordpress contact.php template that would submit forms and send it to my gmail. However, the issue is that it reaches the email only less than half of the time, and it's imperative that I get the rest of the emails.

The next issue related to this is that I did not set up a file that would log the sent out messages. MY question is, basically, - is it possible in any way to retrieve the sent emails that haven't been logged? is there usually a cache of emails maintained by the hosting provider? The only information I have is the IP addresses, and that is hardly any help in this situation.

Thank you.

Comment: Any errors in the logs? Have you checked your Spam folder? Can you show us code? Your question isn't answerable in its current format.

Comment: Have you read any of the previous questions on this subject (look to the Related list lower down this page, on the right sidebar)? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859345/php-mail-not-showing-up-at-gmail-but-shows-up-at-hotmail-and-other-3rd-party-isp?rq=1), for example, may be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Probably being hit by your spam filter. PHP's `mail()` function is prone to this because the mail is sent from the web server, which isn't generally configured with SPL, etc, that receiving mail systems look for to help them filter out spam.

I don't think I can answer the question of how to retrieve lost messages that have already been sent -- only your hosting provider can really help you with that, but my guess would be that they can't help. They are very unlikely to keep hold of outbound emails any longer than necessary. If you're lucky, they might have logs of email events, but even that might not have any useful data in it for you.

One question though: Have you checked your gmail spam box? I'm not a gmail user, but most mail systems do keep a spam box with filtered messages, so that users can retrieve an email that gets marked as spam incorrectly. I'd be surprised if gmail doesn't allow that, and if that's where your mail has gone, then problem solved.

For the future, I suggest switching to use a decent third party library for your mail such as [phpMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/).

The advantage of phpMailer for you in particular is that it can be configured to send mail via gmail, which means you can send it to yourself from own account. This should be pretty much bullet proof as far as spam filtering is concerned. It should also be delivered quicker, since the mail will go direct to Google's servers, without needing to bounce around the internet first.

phpMailer will also make your mail code much cleaner than using the raw `mail()` function, and it allows more advanced features like attachments, without having to write mountains of code.

Hope that helps.